# How to bind classes to another widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here is the font code in question. [Gif Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsuM4.gif)

```
try:
    from tkinter import Toplevel, Listbox, StringVar, BooleanVar, TclError
    from tkinter.ttk import Checkbutton, Frame, Label, Button, Scrollbar, Style, Entry
    from tkinter.font import families, Font
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import Toplevel, Listbox, StringVar, BooleanVar
    from ttk import Checkbutton, Frame, Label, Button, Scrollbar, Style, Entry
    from tkFont import families, Font

from locale import getdefaultlocale

__version__ = "2.0.2"

# --- translation
EN = {"Cancel": "Cancel", "Bold": "Bold", "Italic": "Italic",
      "Underline": "Underline", "Overstrike": "Strikethrough"}
FR = {"Cancel": "Annuler", "Bold": "Gras", "Italic": "Italique",
      "Underline": "Souligné", "Overstrike": "Barré"}
LANGUAGES = {"fr": FR, "en": EN}

if getdefaultlocale()[0][:2] == "fr":
    TR = LANGUAGES["fr"]
else:
    TR = LANGUAGES["en"]


# --- FontChooser class
class FontChooser(Toplevel):
    """.Font chooser dialog."""

    def __init__(self, master, font_dict={}, text="Abcd", title="Font Chooser",
                 **kwargs):
        """
        Create a new FontChooser instance.
        Arguments:
            master: master window
            font_dict: dictionnary, like the one returned by the .actual
                       method of a Font object:
                        {'family': 'DejaVu Sans',
                         'overstrike': False,
                         'size': 12,
                         'slant': 'italic' or 'roman',
                         'underline': False,
                         'weight': 'bold' or 'normal'}
            text: text to be displayed in the preview label
            title: window title
            **kwargs: additional keyword arguments to be passed to
                      Toplevel.__init__
        """
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.title(title)
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.quit)
        self._validate_family = self.register(self.validate_font_family)
        self._validate_size = self.register(self.validate_font_size)

        # --- variable storing the chosen font
        self.res = ""

        style = Style(self)
        style.configure("prev.TLabel", background="white")
        bg = style.lookup("TLabel", "background")
        self.configure(bg=bg)

        # --- family list
        self.fonts = list(set(families()))
        self.fonts.append("TkDefaultFont")
        self.fonts.sort()
        for i in range(len(self.fonts)):
            self.fonts[i] = self.fonts[i].replace(" ", "\ ")
        max_length = int(2.5 * max([len(font) for font in self.fonts])) // 3
        self.sizes = ["%i" % i for i in (list(range(6, 17)) + list(range(18, 32, 2)))]
        # --- font default
        font_dict["weight"] = font_dict.get("weight", "normal")
        font_dict["slant"] = font_dict.get("slant", "roman")
        font_dict["underline"] = font_dict.get("underline", False)
        font_dict["overstrike"] = font_dict.get("overstrike", False)
        font_dict["family"] = font_dict.get("family",
                                            self.fonts[0].replace('\ ', ' '))
        font_dict["size"] = font_dict.get("size", 10)

        # --- creation of the widgets
        # ------ style parameters (bold, italic ...)
        options_frame = Frame(self, relief='groove', borderwidth=2)
        self.font_family = StringVar(self, " ".join(self.fonts))
        self.font_size = StringVar(self, " ".join(self.sizes))
        self.var_bold = BooleanVar(self, font_dict["weight"] == "bold")
        b_bold = Checkbutton(options_frame, text=TR["Bold"],
                             command=self.toggle_bold,
                             variable=self.var_bold)
        b_bold.grid(row=0, sticky="w", padx=4, pady=(4, 2))
        self.var_italic = BooleanVar(self, font_dict["slant"] == "italic")
        b_italic = Checkbutton(options_frame, text=TR["Italic"],
                               command=self.toggle_italic,
                               variable=self.var_italic)
        b_italic.grid(row=1, sticky="w", padx=4, pady=2)
        self.var_underline = BooleanVar(self, font_dict["underline"])
        b_underline = Checkbutton(options_frame, text=TR["Underline"],
                                  command=self.toggle_underline,
                                  variable=self.var_underline)
        b_underline.grid(row=2, sticky="w", padx=4, pady=2)
        self.var_overstrike = BooleanVar(self, font_dict["overstrike"])
        b_overstrike = Checkbutton(options_frame, text=TR["Overstrike"],
                                   variable=self.var_overstrike,
                                   command=self.toggle_overstrike)
        b_overstrike.grid(row=3, sticky="w", padx=4, pady=(2, 4))
        # ------ Size and family
        self.var_size = StringVar(self)
        self.entry_family = Entry(self, width=max_length, validate="key",
                                  validatecommand=(self._validate_family, "%d", "%S",
                                                   "%i", "%s", "%V"))
        self.entry_size = Entry(self, width=4, validate="key",
                                textvariable=self.var_size,
                                validatecommand=(self._validate_size, "%d", "%P", "%V"))
        self.list_family = Listbox(self, selectmode="browse",
                                   listvariable=self.font_family,
                                   highlightthickness=0,
                                   exportselection=False,
                                   width=max_length)
        self.list_size = Listbox(self, selectmode="browse",
                                 listvariable=self.font_size,
                                 highlightthickness=0,
                                 exportselection=False,
                                 width=4)
        scroll_family = Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical',
                                  command=self.list_family.yview)
        scroll_size = Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical',
                                command=self.list_size.yview)
        self.preview_font = Font(self, **font_dict)
        if len(text) > 30:
            text = text[:30]
        self.preview = Label(self, relief="groove", style="prev.TLabel",
                             text=text, font=self.preview_font,
                             anchor="center")

        # --- widget configuration
        self.list_family.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_family.set)
        self.list_size.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_size.set)

        self.entry_family.insert(0, font_dict["family"])
        self.entry_family.selection_clear()
        self.entry_family.icursor("end")
        self.entry_size.insert(0, font_dict["size"])

        try:
            i = self.fonts.index(self.entry_family.get().replace(" ", "\ "))
        except ValueError:
            # unknown font
            i = 0
        self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
        self.list_family.selection_set(i)
        self.list_family.see(i)
        try:
            i = self.sizes.index(self.entry_size.get())
            self.list_size.selection_clear(0, "end")
            self.list_size.selection_set(i)
            self.list_size.see(i)
        except ValueError:
            # size not in list
            pass

        self.entry_family.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew",
                               pady=(10, 1), padx=(10, 0))
        self.entry_size.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ew",
                             pady=(10, 1), padx=(10, 0))
        self.list_family.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew",
                              pady=(1, 10), padx=(10, 0))
        self.list_size.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew",
                            pady=(1, 10), padx=(10, 0))
        scroll_family.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns', pady=(1, 10))
        scroll_size.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='ns', pady=(1, 10))
        options_frame.grid(row=0, column=4, rowspan=2,
                           padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=10)

        self.preview.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky="eswn",
                          padx=10, pady=(0, 10), ipadx=4, ipady=4)

        button_frame = Frame(self)
        button_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=5, pady=(0, 10), padx=10)

        Button(button_frame, text="Ok",
               command=self.ok).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, sticky='ew')
        Button(button_frame, text=TR["Cancel"],
               command=self.quit).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=4, sticky='ew')
        self.list_family.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.update_entry_family)
        self.list_size.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.update_entry_size,
                            add=True)
        self.list_family.bind("<KeyPress>", self.keypress)
        self.entry_family.bind("<Return>", self.change_font_family)
        self.entry_family.bind("<Tab>", self.tab)
        self.entry_size.bind("<Return>", self.change_font_size)

        self.entry_family.bind("<Down>", self.down_family)
        self.entry_size.bind("<Down>", self.down_size)

        self.entry_family.bind("<Up>", self.up_family)
        self.entry_size.bind("<Up>", self.up_size)

        # bind Ctrl+A to select all instead of go to beginning
        self.bind_class("TEntry", "<Control-a>", self.select_all)

        self.wait_visibility(self)
        self.grab_set()
        self.entry_family.focus_set()
        self.lift()

    def select_all(self, event):
        """Select all entry content."""
        event.widget.selection_range(0, "end")

    def keypress(self, event):
        """Select the first font whose name begin by the key pressed."""
        key = event.char.lower()
        l = [i for i in self.fonts if i[0].lower() == key]
        if l:
            i = self.fonts.index(l[0])
            self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
            self.list_family.selection_set(i)
            self.list_family.see(i)
            self.update_entry_family()

    def up_family(self, event):
        """Navigate in the family listbox with up key."""
        try:
            i = self.list_family.curselection()[0]
            self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
            if i <= 0:
                i = len(self.fonts)
            self.list_family.see(i - 1)
            self.list_family.select_set(i - 1)
        except TclError:
            self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
            i = len(self.fonts)
            self.list_family.see(i - 1)
            self.list_family.select_set(i - 1)
        self.list_family.event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>')

    def up_size(self, event):
        """Navigate in the size listbox with up key."""
        try:
            s = self.var_size.get()
            if s in self.sizes:
                i = self.sizes.index(s)
            elif s:
                sizes = list(self.sizes)
                sizes.append(s)
                sizes.sort(key=lambda x: int(x))
                i = sizes.index(s)
            else:
                i = 0
            self.list_size.selection_clear(0, "end")
            if i <= 0:
                i = len(self.sizes)
            self.list_size.see(i - 1)
            self.list_size.select_set(i - 1)
        except TclError:
            i = len(self.sizes)
            self.list_size.see(i - 1)
            self.list_size.select_set(i - 1)
        self.list_size.event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>')

    def down_family(self, event):
        """Navigate in the family listbox with down key."""
        try:
            i = self.list_family.curselection()[0]
            self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
            if i >= len(self.fonts):
                i = -1
            self.list_family.see(i + 1)
            self.list_family.select_set(i + 1)
        except TclError:
            self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
            self.list_family.see(0)
            self.list_family.select_set(0)
        self.list_family.event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>')

    def down_size(self, event):
        """Navigate in the size listbox with down key."""
        try:
            s = self.var_size.get()
            if s in self.sizes:
                i = self.sizes.index(s)
            elif s:
                sizes = list(self.sizes)
                sizes.append(s)
                sizes.sort(key=lambda x: int(x))
                i = sizes.index(s) - 1
            else:
                s = len(self.sizes) - 1
            self.list_size.selection_clear(0, "end")
            if i < len(self.sizes) - 1:
                self.list_size.selection_set(i + 1)
                self.list_size.see(i + 1)
            else:
                self.list_size.see(0)
                self.list_size.select_set(0)
        except TclError:
            self.list_size.selection_set(0)
        self.list_size.event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>')

    def toggle_bold(self):
        """Update font preview weight."""
        b = self.var_bold.get()
        self.preview_font.configure(weight=["normal", "bold"][b])

    def toggle_italic(self):
        """Update font preview slant."""
        b = self.var_italic.get()
        self.preview_font.configure(slant=["roman", "italic"][b])

    def toggle_underline(self):
        """Update font preview underline."""
        b = self.var_underline.get()
        self.preview_font.configure(underline=b)

    def toggle_overstrike(self):
        """Update font preview overstrike."""
        b = self.var_overstrike.get()
        self.preview_font.configure(overstrike=b)

    def change_font_family(self, event=None):
        """Update font preview family."""
        family = self.entry_family.get()
        if family.replace(" ", "\ ") in self.fonts:
            self.preview_font.configure(family=family)

    def change_font_size(self, event=None):
        """Update font preview size."""
        size = int(self.var_size.get())
        self.preview_font.configure(size=size)

    def validate_font_size(self, d, ch, V):
        """Validation of the size entry content."""
        l = [i for i in self.sizes if i[:len(ch)] == ch]
        i = None
        if l:
            i = self.sizes.index(l[0])
        elif ch.isdigit():
            sizes = list(self.sizes)
            sizes.append(ch)
            sizes.sort(key=lambda x: int(x))
            i = min(sizes.index(ch), len(self.sizes))
        if i is not None:
            self.list_size.selection_clear(0, "end")
            self.list_size.selection_set(i)
            deb = self.list_size.nearest(0)
            fin = self.list_size.nearest(self.list_size.winfo_height())
            if V != "forced":
                if i < deb or i > fin:
                    self.list_size.see(i)
                return True
        if d == '1':
            return ch.isdigit()
        else:
            return True

    def tab(self, event):
        """Move at the end of selected text on tab press."""
        self.entry_family = event.widget
        self.entry_family.selection_clear()
        self.entry_family.icursor("end")
        return "break"

    def validate_font_family(self, action, modif, pos, prev_txt, V):
        """Completion of the text in the entry with existing font names."""
        if self.entry_family.selection_present():
            sel = self.entry_family.selection_get()
            txt = prev_txt.replace(sel, '')
        else:
            txt = prev_txt
        if action == "0":
            txt = txt[:int(pos)] + txt[int(pos) + 1:]
            return True
        else:
            txt = txt[:int(pos)] + modif + txt[int(pos):]
            ch = txt.replace(" ", "\ ")
            l = [i for i in self.fonts if i[:len(ch)] == ch]
            if l:
                i = self.fonts.index(l[0])
                self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
                self.list_family.selection_set(i)
                deb = self.list_family.nearest(0)
                fin = self.list_family.nearest(self.list_family.winfo_height())
                index = self.entry_family.index("insert")
                self.entry_family.delete(0, "end")
                self.entry_family.insert(0, l[0].replace("\ ", " "))
                self.entry_family.selection_range(index + 1, "end")
                self.entry_family.icursor(index + 1)
                if V != "forced":
                    if i < deb or i > fin:
                        self.list_family.see(i)
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def update_entry_family(self, event=None):
        """Update family entry when an item is selected in the family listbox."""
        #  family = self.list_family.get("@%i,%i" % (event.x , event.y))
        family = self.list_family.get(self.list_family.curselection()[0])
        self.entry_family.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_family.insert(0, family)
        self.entry_family.selection_clear()
        self.entry_family.icursor("end")
        self.change_font_family()

    def update_entry_size(self, event):
        """Update size entry when an item is selected in the size listbox."""
        #  size = self.list_size.get("@%i,%i" % (event.x , event.y))
        size = self.list_size.get(self.list_size.curselection()[0])
        self.var_size.set(size)
        self.change_font_size()

    def ok(self):
        """Validate choice."""
        self.res = self.preview_font.actual()
        self.quit()

    def get_res(self):
        """Return chosen font."""
        return self.res

    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()


def askfont(master=None, text="Abcd", title="Font Chooser", **font_args):
    """
    Open the font chooser and return the chosen font.
    Arguments:
        master: master window
        text: sample text to be displayed in the font chooser
        title: dialog title
        font_args: family, size, slant (=roman/italic),
                   weight (=normal/bold), underline (bool), overstrike (bool)
    """
    chooser = FontChooser(master, font_args, text, title)
    chooser.wait_window(chooser)
    return chooser.get_res()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """Example."""
    try:
        from tkinter import Tk
    except ImportError:
        from Tkinter import Tk
    from sys import platform

    root = Tk()
    style = Style(root)
    if "win" == platform[:3]:
        style.theme_use('vista')
    elif "darwin" in platform:
        style.theme_use('clam')
    else:
        style.theme_use('clam')
    bg = style.lookup("TLabel", "background")
    root.configure(bg=bg)
    label = Label(root, text='Chosen font: ')
    label.pack(padx=10, pady=(10, 4))

    def callback():
        font = askfont(root, title="Choose a font")
        if font:
            # spaces in the family name need to be escaped
            font['family'] = font['family'].replace(' ', '\ ')
            font_str = "%(family)s %(size)i %(weight)s %(slant)s" % font
            if font['underline']:
                font_str += ' underline'
            if font['overstrike']:
                font_str += ' overstrike'
            label.configure(font=font_str,
                            text='Chosen font: ' + font_str.replace('\ ', ' '))

    Button(root, text='Font Chooser',
           command=callback).pack(padx=10, pady=(4, 10))
    root.mainloop()
```

I need 1) the 'choose a font' window should be called immediately after clicking on the 'Font' menu item.

2) after clicking 'Ok' in the 'choose a font' window, the text font should change in the text widget.

Here is my example GUI.

```
from tkinter import *

def edit_font():
    #the edited class

root=Tk()
text=Text(root)
text.pack()

count = 0

king=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=king)

view= Menu(king, tearoff=0)
view2=Menu(view, tearoff=0)
view2.add_command(label='Font',command=edit_font)

view.add_cascade(label='Text', menu=view2)
king.add_cascade(label='View', menu=view)

root.mainloop()
```

I tried replacing:

```
bg = style.lookup("TLabel", "background")
        root.configure(bg=bg)
        label = Label(root, text='Chosen font: ')
        label.pack(padx=10, pady=(10, 4))

        def callback():
            font = askfont(root, title="Choose a font")
            if font:
                # spaces in the family name need to be escaped
                font['family'] = font['family'].replace(' ', '\ ')
                font_str = "%(family)s %(size)i %(weight)s %(slant)s" % font
                if font['underline']:
                    font_str += ' underline'
                if font['overstrike']:
                    font_str += ' overstrike'
                label.configure(font=font_str,
                                text='Chosen font: ' +font_str.replace('\',' '))
```

with:

```
 bg = style.lookup("TLabel", "background")
        root.configure(bg=bg)


        def callback():
            global text # widget text
            font = askfont(root, title="Choose a font")
            if font:
                # spaces in the family name need to be escaped
                font['family'] = font['family'].replace(' ', '\ ')
                font_str = "%(family)s %(size)i %(weight)s %(slant)s" % font
                if font['underline']:
                    font_str += ' underline'
                if font['overstrike']:
                    font_str += ' overstrike'
                text.configure(font=font_str)
                text.insert=(1.0,font_str.replace('\ ', ' '))
```

I've managed to change the font of the text in the Text widget, but the size of the Text widget changes depending on the font selected, how can this be avoided?

Comment: What have you tried? I see nothing in your code that shows you have tried yourself.

Comment: You've posted way too much code. We need a [mcve], not a complete program.

Comment: @BryanOakley The first section of code is likely something the OP found and is trying to use it in conjunction with their small bit of code below it. I don't think they can reduce the first bit of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need to make this work is located in the `callback()` and `askfont()` methods in the font code. You need to take elements from `callback()` and `askfont()` and incorporate them into your code.

You will also need to import the font code. Lets say the Font code is in the same directory as our `main.py` and we call this file `font.py`.

UPDATE: To address the latest addition to your question all you need to do is `text.pack(expand=True, fill="x")`. This will tell the text widget to fill the frame or window it is in.

Your code should look something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import font as pyfont
import tkinter.font as xFont

def edit_font():
    # this line waits for askfont to return the new chosen font.
    font = pyfont.askfont(root, title="Choose a font")

    # this if statement will convert the dictionary that is returned from
    # the askfont function into something we can use to configure the texbox.
    if font:
            # spaces in the family name need to be escaped
            font['family'] = font['family'].replace(' ', '\ ')
            font_str = "%(family)s %(size)i %(weight)s %(slant)s" % font
            if font['underline']:
                font_str += ' underline'
            if font['overstrike']:
                font_str += ' overstrike'
            text.configure(font=font_str)

root=Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

text=Text(root, font=xFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=10))
text.pack(expand=True, fill="x")

king=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=king)

view= Menu(king, tearoff=0)
view2=Menu(view, tearoff=0)
view2.add_command(label='Font',command=edit_font)

view.add_cascade(label='Text', menu=view2)
king.add_cascade(label='View', menu=view)

root.mainloop()
```

UPDATE:

Because in the comments you stated the code is all in the same file that changes things. I recommend against this and you should separate your code to their own files and import what you need.

That said to address the issues at hand please see the below code.

At the bottom is your GUI code. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import Toplevel, Listbox, StringVar, BooleanVar, TclError
    from tkinter.ttk import Checkbutton, Frame, Label, Button, Scrollbar, Style, Entry
    from tkinter.font import families, Font
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    from Tkinter import Toplevel, Listbox, StringVar, BooleanVar
    from ttk import Checkbutton, Frame, Label, Button, Scrollbar, Style, Entry
    from tkFont import families, Font

from locale import getdefaultlocale

__version__ = "2.0.2"

# --- translation
EN = {"Cancel": "Cancel", "Bold": "Bold", "Italic": "Italic",
      "Underline": "Underline", "Overstrike": "Strikethrough"}
FR = {"Cancel": "Annuler", "Bold": "Gras", "Italic": "Italique",
      "Underline": "Souligné", "Overstrike": "Barré"}
LANGUAGES = {"fr": FR, "en": EN}

if getdefaultlocale()[0][:2] == "fr":
    TR = LANGUAGES["fr"]
else:
    TR = LANGUAGES["en"]


# --- FontChooser class
class FontChooser(Toplevel):
    """.Font chooser dialog."""

    def __init__(self, master, font_dict={}, text="Abcd", title="Font Chooser",
                 **kwargs):
        """
        Create a new FontChooser instance.
        Arguments:
            master: master window
            font_dict: dictionnary, like the one returned by the .actual
                       method of a Font object:
                        {'family': 'DejaVu Sans',
                         'overstrike': False,
                         'size': 12,
                         'slant': 'italic' or 'roman',
                         'underline': False,
                         'weight': 'bold' or 'normal'}
            text: text to be displayed in the preview label
            title: window title
            **kwargs: additional keyword arguments to be passed to
                      Toplevel.__init__
        """
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.title(title)
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.quit)
        self._validate_family = self.register(self.validate_font_family)
        self._validate_size = self.register(self.validate_font_size)

        # --- variable storing the chosen font
        self.res = ""

        style = Style(self)
        style.configure("prev.TLabel", background="white")
        bg = style.lookup("TLabel", "background")
        self.configure(bg=bg)

        # --- family list
        self.fonts = list(set(families()))
        self.fonts.append("TkDefaultFont")
        self.fonts.sort()
        for i in range(len(self.fonts)):
            self.fonts[i] = self.fonts[i].replace(" ", "\ ")
        max_length = int(2.5 * max([len(font) for font in self.fonts])) // 3
        self.sizes = ["%i" % i for i in (list(range(6, 17)) + list(range(18, 32, 2)))]
        # --- font default
        font_dict["weight"] = font_dict.get("weight", "normal")
        font_dict["slant"] = font_dict.get("slant", "roman")
        font_dict["underline"] = font_dict.get("underline", False)
        font_dict["overstrike"] = font_dict.get("overstrike", False)
        font_dict["family"] = font_dict.get("family",
                                            self.fonts[0].replace('\ ', ' '))
        font_dict["size"] = font_dict.get("size", 10)

        # --- creation of the widgets
        # ------ style parameters (bold, italic ...)
        options_frame = Frame(self, relief='groove', borderwidth=2)
        self.font_family = StringVar(self, " ".join(self.fonts))
        self.font_size = StringVar(self, " ".join(self.sizes))
        self.var_bold = BooleanVar(self, font_dict["weight"] == "bold")
        b_bold = Checkbutton(options_frame, text=TR["Bold"],
                             command=self.toggle_bold,
                             variable=self.var_bold)
        b_bold.grid(row=0, sticky="w", padx=4, pady=(4, 2))
        self.var_italic = BooleanVar(self, font_dict["slant"] == "italic")
        b_italic = Checkbutton(options_frame, text=TR["Italic"],
                               command=self.toggle_italic,
                               variable=self.var_italic)
        b_italic.grid(row=1, sticky="w", padx=4, pady=2)
        self.var_underline = BooleanVar(self, font_dict["underline"])
        b_underline = Checkbutton(options_frame, text=TR["Underline"],
                                  command=self.toggle_underline,
                                  variable=self.var_underline)
        b_underline.grid(row=2, sticky="w", padx=4, pady=2)
        self.var_overstrike = BooleanVar(self, font_dict["overstrike"])
        b_overstrike = Checkbutton(options_frame, text=TR["Overstrike"],
                                   variable=self.var_overstrike,
                                   command=self.toggle_overstrike)
        b_overstrike.grid(row=3, sticky="w", padx=4, pady=(2, 4))
        # ------ Size and family
        self.var_size = StringVar(self)
        self.entry_family = Entry(self, width=max_length, validate="key",
                                  validatecommand=(self._validate_family, "%d", "%S",
                                                   "%i", "%s", "%V"))
        self.entry_size = Entry(self, width=4, validate="key",
                                textvariable=self.var_size,
                                validatecommand=(self._validate_size, "%d", "%P", "%V"))
        self.list_family = Listbox(self, selectmode="browse",
                                   listvariable=self.font_family, highlightthickness=0, exportselection=False, width=max_length)
        self.list_size = Listbox(self, selectmode="browse",
                                 listvariable=self.font_size, highlightthickness=0, exportselection=False, width=4)
        scroll_family = Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.list_family.yview)
        scroll_size = Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.list_size.yview)
        self.preview_font = Font(self, **font_dict)
        if len(text) > 30:
            text = text[:30]
        self.preview = Label(self, relief="groove", style="prev.TLabel", text=text, font=self.preview_font, anchor="center")

        self.list_family.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_family.set)
        self.list_size.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_size.set)
        self.entry_family.insert(0, font_dict["family"])
        self.entry_family.selection_clear()
        self.entry_family.icursor("end")
        self.entry_size.insert(0, font_dict["size"])
        try:
            i = self.fonts.index(self.entry_family.get().replace(" ", "\ "))
        except ValueError:
            i = 0
        self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
        self.list_family.selection_set(i)
        self.list_family.see(i)
        try:
            i = self.sizes.index(self.entry_size.get())
            self.list_size.selection_clear(0, "end")
            self.list_size.selection_set(i)
            self.list_size.see(i)
        except ValueError:
            pass

        self.entry_family.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", pady=(10, 1), padx=(10, 0))
        self.entry_size.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ew", pady=(10, 1), padx=(10, 0))
        self.list_family.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", pady=(1, 10), padx=(10, 0))
        self.list_size.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew", pady=(1, 10), padx=(10, 0))
        scroll_family.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns', pady=(1, 10))
        scroll_size.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='ns', pady=(1, 10))
        options_frame.grid(row=0, column=4, rowspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=10)

        self.preview.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky="eswn", padx=10, pady=(0, 10), ipadx=4, ipady=4)
        button_frame = Frame(self)
        button_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=5, pady=(0, 10), padx=10)
        Button(button_frame, text="Ok", command=self.ok).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, sticky='ew')
        Button(button_frame, text=TR["Cancel"], command=self.quit).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=4, sticky='ew')
        self.list_family.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.update_entry_family)
        self.list_size.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.update_entry_size, add=True)
        self.list_family.bind("<KeyPress>", self.keypress)
        self.entry_family.bind("<Return>", self.change_font_family)
        self.entry_family.bind("<Tab>", self.tab)
        self.entry_size.bind("<Return>", self.change_font_size)
        self.entry_family.bind("<Down>", self.down_family)
        self.entry_size.bind("<Down>", self.down_size)
        self.entry_family.bind("<Up>", self.up_family)
        self.entry_size.bind("<Up>", self.up_size)
        self.bind_class("TEntry", "<Control-a>", self.select_all)

        self.wait_visibility(self)
        self.grab_set()
        self.entry_family.focus_set()
        self.lift()

    def select_all(self, event):
        event.widget.selection_range(0, "end")

    def keypress(self, event):
        key = event.char.lower()
        l = [i for i in self.fonts if i[0].lower() == key]
        if l:
            i = self.fonts.index(l[0])
            self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
            self.list_family.selection_set(i)
            self.list_family.see(i)
            self.update_entry_family()

    def up_family(self, event):
        try:
            i = self.list_family.curselection()[0]
            self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
            if i <= 0:
                i = len(self.fonts)
            self.list_family.see(i - 1)
            self.list_family.select_set(i - 1)
        except TclError:
            self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
            i = len(self.fonts)
            self.list_family.see(i - 1)
            self.list_family.select_set(i - 1)
        self.list_family.event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>')

    def up_size(self, event):
        """Navigate in the size listbox with up key."""
        try:
            s = self.var_size.get()
            if s in self.sizes:
                i = self.sizes.index(s)
            elif s:
                sizes = list(self.sizes)
                sizes.append(s)
                sizes.sort(key=lambda x: int(x))
                i = sizes.index(s)
            else:
                i = 0
            self.list_size.selection_clear(0, "end")
            if i <= 0:
                i = len(self.sizes)
            self.list_size.see(i - 1)
            self.list_size.select_set(i - 1)
        except TclError:
            i = len(self.sizes)
            self.list_size.see(i - 1)
            self.list_size.select_set(i - 1)
        self.list_size.event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>')

    def down_family(self, event):
        """Navigate in the family listbox with down key."""
        try:
            i = self.list_family.curselection()[0]
            self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
            if i >= len(self.fonts):
                i = -1
            self.list_family.see(i + 1)
            self.list_family.select_set(i + 1)
        except TclError:
            self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
            self.list_family.see(0)
            self.list_family.select_set(0)
        self.list_family.event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>')

    def down_size(self, event):
        """Navigate in the size listbox with down key."""
        try:
            s = self.var_size.get()
            if s in self.sizes:
                i = self.sizes.index(s)
            elif s:
                sizes = list(self.sizes)
                sizes.append(s)
                sizes.sort(key=lambda x: int(x))
                i = sizes.index(s) - 1
            else:
                s = len(self.sizes) - 1
            self.list_size.selection_clear(0, "end")
            if i < len(self.sizes) - 1:
                self.list_size.selection_set(i + 1)
                self.list_size.see(i + 1)
            else:
                self.list_size.see(0)
                self.list_size.select_set(0)
        except TclError:
            self.list_size.selection_set(0)
        self.list_size.event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>')

    def toggle_bold(self):
        """Update font preview weight."""
        b = self.var_bold.get()
        self.preview_font.configure(weight=["normal", "bold"][b])

    def toggle_italic(self):
        """Update font preview slant."""
        b = self.var_italic.get()
        self.preview_font.configure(slant=["roman", "italic"][b])

    def toggle_underline(self):
        """Update font preview underline."""
        b = self.var_underline.get()
        self.preview_font.configure(underline=b)

    def toggle_overstrike(self):
        """Update font preview overstrike."""
        b = self.var_overstrike.get()
        self.preview_font.configure(overstrike=b)

    def change_font_family(self, event=None):
        """Update font preview family."""
        family = self.entry_family.get()
        if family.replace(" ", "\ ") in self.fonts:
            self.preview_font.configure(family=family)

    def change_font_size(self, event=None):
        """Update font preview size."""
        size = int(self.var_size.get())
        self.preview_font.configure(size=size)

    def validate_font_size(self, d, ch, V):
        """Validation of the size entry content."""
        l = [i for i in self.sizes if i[:len(ch)] == ch]
        i = None
        if l:
            i = self.sizes.index(l[0])
        elif ch.isdigit():
            sizes = list(self.sizes)
            sizes.append(ch)
            sizes.sort(key=lambda x: int(x))
            i = min(sizes.index(ch), len(self.sizes))
        if i is not None:
            self.list_size.selection_clear(0, "end")
            self.list_size.selection_set(i)
            deb = self.list_size.nearest(0)
            fin = self.list_size.nearest(self.list_size.winfo_height())
            if V != "forced":
                if i < deb or i > fin:
                    self.list_size.see(i)
                return True
        if d == '1':
            return ch.isdigit()
        else:
            return True

    def tab(self, event):
        """Move at the end of selected text on tab press."""
        self.entry_family = event.widget
        self.entry_family.selection_clear()
        self.entry_family.icursor("end")
        return "break"

    def validate_font_family(self, action, modif, pos, prev_txt, V):
        """Completion of the text in the entry with existing font names."""
        if self.entry_family.selection_present():
            sel = self.entry_family.selection_get()
            txt = prev_txt.replace(sel, '')
        else:
            txt = prev_txt
        if action == "0":
            txt = txt[:int(pos)] + txt[int(pos) + 1:]
            return True
        else:
            txt = txt[:int(pos)] + modif + txt[int(pos):]
            ch = txt.replace(" ", "\ ")
            l = [i for i in self.fonts if i[:len(ch)] == ch]
            if l:
                i = self.fonts.index(l[0])
                self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
                self.list_family.selection_set(i)
                deb = self.list_family.nearest(0)
                fin = self.list_family.nearest(self.list_family.winfo_height())
                index = self.entry_family.index("insert")
                self.entry_family.delete(0, "end")
                self.entry_family.insert(0, l[0].replace("\ ", " "))
                self.entry_family.selection_range(index + 1, "end")
                self.entry_family.icursor(index + 1)
                if V != "forced":
                    if i < deb or i > fin:
                        self.list_family.see(i)
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def update_entry_family(self, event=None):
        """Update family entry when an item is selected in the family listbox."""
        #  family = self.list_family.get("@%i,%i" % (event.x , event.y))
        family = self.list_family.get(self.list_family.curselection()[0])
        self.entry_family.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_family.insert(0, family)
        self.entry_family.selection_clear()
        self.entry_family.icursor("end")
        self.change_font_family()

    def update_entry_size(self, event):
        """Update size entry when an item is selected in the size listbox."""
        #  size = self.list_size.get("@%i,%i" % (event.x , event.y))
        size = self.list_size.get(self.list_size.curselection()[0])
        self.var_size.set(size)
        self.change_font_size()

    def ok(self):
        """Validate choice."""
        self.res = self.preview_font.actual()
        self.quit()

    def get_res(self):
        """Return chosen font."""
        return self.res

    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()


def askfont(master=None, text="Abcd", title="Font Chooser", **font_args):
    chooser = FontChooser(master, font_args, text, title)
    chooser.wait_window(chooser)
    return chooser.get_res()

def edit_font():
    font = askfont(root, title="Choose a font")
    if font:
            font['family'] = font['family'].replace(' ', '\ ')
            font_str = "%(family)s %(size)i %(weight)s %(slant)s" % font
            if font['underline']:
                font_str += ' underline'
            if font['overstrike']:
                font_str += ' overstrike'
            text.configure(font=font_str)

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
# added weights so the widget resizes correctly with window
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

text=tk.Text(root, font=Font(family="Helvetica", size=10))
text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

king=tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=king)

view=tk.Menu(king, tearoff=0)
view2=tk.Menu(view, tearoff=0)
view2.add_command(label='Font',command=edit_font)

view.add_cascade(label='Text', menu=view2)
king.add_cascade(label='View', menu=view)

root.mainloop()
```